# WSGI (python) how to get POST data from an HTML form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

This is the HTML form that "gets" /1.wsgi

```
<form action="/1.wsgi" method="get">
<input type="text" name="one">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

this is my 1.wsgi script:

```
from cgi import parse_qs
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    o = parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
    oo = o.get('one', [''])[0]
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield oo
```

works very nicely, *BUT* I would like to use `POST` method rather than `GET`. I understand in html form `"get"` has to be changed to `"post"` but what exactly must I do in the WSGI script?

Comment: Have you considered using one of the miriad Python WSGI frameworks? They'd make this a lot easier by taking the parsing work out your hands..

Comment: *is there such thing as pylons* why yes there is!

Answer (score 4):

A POST sends the encoded form data in the request body; read `CONTENT_LENGTH` bytes from the `wsgi.input` stream:

```
try:
    request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
except (ValueError):
    request_body_size = 0

request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
o = parse_qs(request_body)
```

This is assuming you are still using the default form encoding, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.